# Replace individual page numbers with mathematical expressions

Tags: math-mode, page-numbering

I'd like to replace a few individual page numbers in a document with mathematical expressions, like `$a^0$` for page 1, `$2(2)^1$` for 4, etc.  I don't have a ToC or index, so I'm not concerned about the actual page numbers changing; just what's printed at the bottom of the page.

I'm not sure it's helpful, but here's a MWE.  Instead of a 1 at the bottom of the page, I want `$a^0$`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    Body of page, which is about exponential functions
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Macro `\thepage` can be redefined to give the desired representation of the page number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \ifcase\value{page}%
    0%
  \or
    $a^0$%
  \or
    $2^1$%
  \or
    3%
  \or
    $2^2$%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{page}=9 %
      $3^3$
    \else
     \arabic{page}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\section{My document}
\label{sec:doc}
Body of page, which is about exponential functions.\\
Reference to section \ref{sec:doc} at page \pageref{sec:doc}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: for a short document, marvelous!  but what about a 400-page book?  might be able to use some other counter for the `\ifcase` statement, trigger its resetting somewhere on the affected page, and have a test (in the folio code?) when the page is set to make sure it's done only once.  (of course, interspersing such nonstandard page numbers in a 400-page book would make life very difficult for the reader ... but i suppose a list somewhere equating the special numbers to the nominal page numbers might soften the pain.)