# Is it possible to specify page numbers that are words, e.g. "Title"?

Tags: pdf, page-numbering

I suppose this might also go on SuperUser, but I'm only interested in it insofar as implementing it in LaTeX, so I'll ask here.

I feel certain that I've seen PDF's where the actual PDF page number of (for example) the title page is not 1 or i, or any of the standard choices I know are possible in LaTeX, but rather the word "Title", like this:

[image]

(the numbering would then continue as usual, with the second page in the document being indicated as "1" in the white box, etc.)

This is only a mock-up, because unfortunately I can't find any examples of PDFs that are like this (perhaps I've only imagined it?) but hopefully I have specified the idea well enough, and I'd like to know if it's possible to do in LaTeX.

Comment: have you seen [replace-individual-page-numbers-with-mathematical-expressions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78117/replace-individual-page-numbers-with-mathematical-expressions)?

Comment: @cmhughes: Yes, but that appears only to deal with what is displayed *on the page*. I'm interested in specifying the metadata of the PDF so that a given page number is a word.

Comment: @cmhughes Have you seen [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378)? `;)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Digging into `hyperref` source code, I discovered a macro of promising name: `\thispdfpagelabel`. I tried it with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispdfpagelabel{Test}
\lipsum
\newpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Bingo! The resulting pdf has the pages numbered from 1 to 4, as usual, but Adobe Reader showed this in the status bar:

[image: Screenshot]